# Why are my OnTriggerEnter2D events firing only on android in a situation they shouldnt be firing?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-physics

[Related reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/8tkptt/unity_bug_in_android_ontriggerenter2d_firing_on/e18a2kr/?context=3)

I have been struggling with a collision bug that only happens when I install the game on an android device.

I have a very simple game set up like air hockey. Some objects to represent paddles, a puck, a couple of end zones for scoring, and walls. Whenever I move one of the paddles and collide it against the puck at a very low velocity, my ontriggerenter2d events are firing on my end zones even though the puck is nowhere near the end zones. Here is my OnTriggerEnter2d function in my end zone controller script:

```
// EndZone
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Other)
{

Debug.Log("EndZone::OnTriggerEnter2D " + playerNumber.ToString());
    if (Other.gameObject.tag == "Puck")
    {
        Observer.SendMessage("Score", "" + playerNumber.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other information could be relevant. I will provide anything asked for including my entire project if deemed necessary.

This bug only happens when I actually build to android, not when I run the game on desktop. Even if I'm using a tablet and unity remote to provide input.

Update: Some more information I just found out:

Code from my PaddleController connected to my paddles:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    Debug.Log("PaddleController::OnCollisionEnter2D " + coll.gameObject.tag);
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Puck")
    {
        // Commenting out the following "AddForce" statement causes the bug to not happen
        coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(CurrVelocity);
        SoundManager.RandomizeSfxPitch(click);
    }
}

void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Puck")
    {
        // Commenting out the following "AddForce" statement causes the bug to not happen
        coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(CurrVelocity);
    }
}
```

Comment: The questions sounds like a magic to me. It's very possible this is not what's really going on. I think that your object touched another object. Log the object that is detected and you'll be surprised.  `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D Other)
{Debug.Log(Other.name);}`

Comment: @Programmer I will do this when I get home. I'm currently at work. However, I already ran some android studio debugging and found that both endzone ontriggerEnter2D events are firing. Not only that but the puck gameobject tag is exclusive to the puck and both triggered events send the "Score" message

Comment: Check the object it is touching when you get home. That's the easiest way to find why this is happening.

Comment: @Programmer I did what you suggested. Here's the debug output: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VsBR6NRx). Clearly, both endzones are being triggered by the puck. But also, interestingly, the paddle.